# Learning React, TypeError from Babel browser.min.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Trying to learn React.js and am at a rode block. I have seen many similar problems on here and tried their solutions with switching versions and changing syntax(React and React.DOM, Parenthesis around html) but no luck. Others have said it is not supported anymore as well. If that is the case I am not sure where to go from here as I am very new and learning from an older tutorial. Any help or insight would be helpful, thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My First Component</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="HelloMessage"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return <div>Hello World</div>;
            }
        });

        React.render(
            <HelloMessage />,
            document.getElementById('HelloMessage');
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Gives me the TypeError:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend checking out this new (kind of official) tutorial - https://reacttraining.com/online/react-fundamentals

Answer (score 1):

This is because, although you have `babel-core`, you do not have the necessary `preset-react` configuration for `babel`.

Therefore, `babel` does not know what to do with `jsx`.

For example:

`return <div>Hello World</div>;`

The [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) will show you several ways you can include the necessary presets.

Comment: Thank you I will start from there.

Comment: No problem.  Also, if your goal is to first learn plain react without things like webpack and all it's configuration, you can use https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app or, take a look at a (paid) course like: https://frontendmasters.com/courses/complete-intro-react/?u=0f7234162ee993e6df7ffcbdf45f351fc8a6153c which goes over how to use react, from scratch, without any special build tools, and then adds complexity as its needed to make things easier.  Highly recommended.

Comment: I used this article and was able get my environment setup. https://www.kirupa.com/react/setting_up_react_environment.htm

Comment: Nice. Webpack is amazing.  It took me a while to understand how to do things like import images, fonts, video, etc with it.  If you have trouble, be sure to ask another question. Enjoy.